# Returning the most common text from a Column

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a function that returns the most occurring text form a text filed in MS Access?
More like the `Mode` string (the string that appears the most in a column).
I have tried `DlookUp` but I don't know how to filter out to return the single string of interest.

The data on the query looks like:

```
CustomerNo PurchasedItem FinacialYearDate PruchaseDate
123        Books         01/01/2021       01/02/2022
123        Books         01/01/2021       03/03/2022
123        Books         01/01/2021       21/02/2022
123        Note pads     01/01/2021       01/02/2022
124        Pens          01/01/2021       01/01/2022
124        Note pads     01/01/2021       01/03/2022
124        Books         01/01/2021       01/03/2022
```

Expected Result for `CustomerNo` `123` should be: `Books`

This is my approach:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.lblMostPurchsedItemThisYear.Caption = "(" & DLookUp("PurchasedItem", "qryCustomerProfile", "[CustomerNo] = txtCustomerNo AND [PurchasedItem] = ..... AND DateDiff('d', [FinacialYearDate], [PruchaseDate]) < 365") & ")"
End Sub
```

Thank you SO.

Comment: Maybe you could create a separate list with the distinct values for each customer no, then count how many instances there are of that value and then find which one was counted the most times.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your query based on this (adding other parameters as required):

```
SELECT TOP 1  PurchasedItem
FROM YourTable t
where CustomerNo=[pCustomerNo]
group by PurchasedItem
ORDER BY Count(*) desc;
```

And use this in the `DLookup`

Comment: A Dlookup on the above will pop-up the parameter window looking for the parameter.

Comment: @KostasK. Is the DLOOKUP really needed in the above query? I assume the query will order the field by using the `count` function which makes it resolved since it only selects the TOP row.

Comment: @Fil Simply it won't work. You can open a recordset through a `QueryDef` so you can pass the parameter, but you will probably need to replace the `Count(*)` with the actual count column - I don't think it works in Access.

Comment: @kostask, thanks for the warning. I intended to show the SQL syntax for getting the item requested, it wasn't meant to be a complete replacement for the assignment by dlookup.